# Voltage regulator SOT23-5 identification

Tags: voltage-regulator, sot23

can somebody help me to identify SMD electronic component

Package: SOT23-5
Marking: S2-00 PNA995

I try to repair Dell computer and BIOS chip does not have 3.3 volt. Beeping the circuit BIOS SOP8 chip pin 8 connected to PNA995 pins 1 and 3.

My guess is that this component is 3.3 volt regulator.

[image]

The closest I could get to is probably that this component is made by Panasonic.

Thank you in advance
Polar Bear

Comment: Searching for S2-00 IC got me to https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32788785927.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2pol#nav-specification, which suggests it is indeed a low dropout regulator.  An alternative part number is listed on that page: UP7707, which led me to this page: http://micro-bridge.com/LDO.asp, where there is a replacement part listed: EUP7907.  And there is a datasheet for the EUP7907: http://www.micro-bridge.com/data/Eutech/EUP7907.pdf.  None of these are very authoritative sources, but it might get you on your way.

Comment: Took the same search methods of Tony and I'm fairly confident that it is the UP7707 as the S2-00 marking is the product marking.